# Tailwind hot-reload takes more than 40 seconds to refresh when I use Twin.Macro inline CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Suddenly my Tailwind started to load very slow when refreshing (hot-reload).

After some research, I found that `@tailwind utilities;` should not be imported via `globals.css` so I created a new file called `tailwind-utils.css`. ( `@tailwind base` and `@tailwind components` are also imported from different file called `tailwind.css`.)

Then, I imported those files in the `_app.tsx` like below

```
import '../styles/tailwind.css'
import '../styles/tailwind-utils.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { GlobalStyles } from 'twin.macro'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <GlobalStyles />
            <Component {...pageProps} />,
        </>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

And here is my `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    important: true,
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    darkMode: false,
    plugins: [require('daisyui')]
}
```

Currently, the hot-reload takes more than 40seconds to load so I want to figure a way to go faster loading.

Here is my `globals.css`

```
/* @tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities; */

html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell,
        Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM Plex Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
```

I also noticed that hot-reloads complete in a second when I write CSS from the module, not inline. But when I update CSS using Twin.Macro syntax (Inline CSS) it takes lots time...